# How to load a post into an empty div tag anywhere across the pages?

Tags: posts, text

Absolute beginner question:
I need to load text into specific div tags across the page.
On my html mockup its a lorem ispum text box waiting for wordpress to load the real content.
So, how do i control the real content and its relation with the div box text on the page?
Can it be a post, so i can manage it from the dashboard?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways.

One it's to use simple [querys](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and using the **p** parameter to retrive a particular post like it's explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post).
Something like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'p=123' );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Where 123 it's the post id from where you need the data (the_content).

Or you can query the content from a single post using [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function.
Like this:

```
$postid = 123;
$queryp = get_post($postid);
$content = $queryp->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

Where 123, again, it's the postid from where you need to extract the content.

And i think [wp_get_single_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_single_post) function should work too.

Then you can control your content everywhere just extracting the desired data from certains posts by postid

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, TCattd. I'm not sure about where to put the code(which page, which part) but I'll give it a try. Thx again.